# selectToUISlider setting value incorrectly

Tags: jquery-ui

I have a standard `<select>..</select>` element with which I have a slider created by selectToUISlider()
The problem is that when the slider moves the option in the dropdown does not change. Additionally it sets `selected="selected"` on each element as the slider is moved so that when the form is submitted multiple values are POSTed emulating a multiple select option.

I've spent ages trying to get to the bottom of this but no luck. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across the same problem when trying to achieve similar functionality as mentioned by you.

The problem is whenever a slider is moved it keeps setting the "selected" attribute of the select list without clearing up previously selected item. I have added a script to clear previously selected option items before setting the new one as selected.

Look/search for the text at line number 92(..ish) of the jquery script file.

```
   //control original select menu
   var currSelect = jQuery('#' + thisHandle.attr('id').split('handle_')[1]);
   currSelect.find('option').eq(ui.value).attr('selected', 'selected');
```

and insert this code between 2 lines...

```
   currSelect.find('option[selected]').removeAttr('selected');
```

so final code should look like this...

```
   //control original select menu
   var currSelect = jQuery('#' + thisHandle.attr('id').split('handle_')[1]);
   currSelect.find('option[selected]').removeAttr('selected');
   currSelect.find('option').eq(ui.value).attr('selected', 'selected');
```

I hope it helps.
Feel free to ask any further question.

Comment: Perhaps you should file a bug report?

Comment: Yes I should and I will do it.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is quite old but I recently stuggled with this and maybe my solution helps someone. I had this same problem when using more recent versions of jQuery (>jQuery 1.6.1) and JQueryUI and trying to use selectToUISlider with them.

I found my solution (using properties insted of attributes) just replacing in the selectToUISlider.js script, in line 98

This

```
currSelect.find('option').eq(ui.value).attr('selected', 'selected');
```

for this

```
currSelect.find('option').eq(ui.value).prop('selected', true);
```

You can find the "Why" on this answer, which helped me to find this solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5876747/2285806

You can read also the jQuery API entry for prop() to find more information and read important notes on browser backwards compatibility:
http://api.jquery.com/prop/